# Jquery Slider - get every numeric value of the slider? not only on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

I'm attempting to create a jquery slider that basically makes text fade in and out (and pictures) with the jquery slider and a switch statement. here is the code:

```
$(function(){
            $sliderValue="";
            // Slider
            $('#slider').slider({
                orientation: "vertical",
                value : 100,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                            $("#slider_value").val(ui.value);
                            //$("p#time1").fadeTo("slow", 0.90);

                      },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    $sliderValue=ui.value;
                      }
            });
            $('#slider').bind('slide', function() {
                var sV = $sliderValue;
                switch (sV) { 
                     case 100: 
                     $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 1);
                     break; 
                     case 90: 
                     $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 0.60);
                     break; 
                     case 80: 
                     $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 0.30);
                     break; 
                     case 75: 
                     $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 0.00);
                     break; 
                 }
            });


        });
```

so basically this switch statement only fires on mouse out (lame!) and I don't know why! any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I need it to update as I scroll the slider (without having to stop clicking).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that the switch statement isn't running, its just running with old data.

It looks like you are only ever setting the value of $sliderValue in the stop event.  However, you are then using $sliderValue in your switch statement.

I'm also not sure that it is necessary to have to slide events (one set by the bind and one in the initialization.  I would change it to look like this.

```
$(function(){  
        $sliderValue="";  
        // Slider  
        $('#slider').slider({  
            orientation: "vertical",  
            value : 100,  
            min: 0,  
            max: 100,  
            slide: function(event, ui) {  
                        $("#slider_value").val(ui.value);  
                        switch (ui.value) {   
                             case 100:   
                             $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 1);  
                             break;   
                             case 90:   
                             $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 0.60);  
                             break;   
                             case 80:   
                             $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 0.30);  
                             break;   
                             case 75:   
                             $("p#time1").fadeTo("fast", 0.00);  
                              break;
                         }  

                  },  
            stop: function(event, ui) {  
                $sliderValue=ui.value;  
                  }  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my comments:

1. I don't think you have to do both: setting the "slide" option and binding the slide event handler. I believe this will register two event handlers to the same slide event (You can try console.log something in the two functions to see the behavior). So you just need to choose one.
2. If you want to change the opacity while sliding, the fadeTo() effect might be unnecessary  (because of the delay). You can just change the css opacity.
3. Because the opacity value is between 0 and 1, you can also set the min/max/step option to be the same range and get rid of some calculation.

Here is the code and the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fLmKC/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Slider
   $('#slider').slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      value : 1,
      min: 0,   
      max: 1,   
      step: 0.01,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
         $("p#time1").css("opacity", ui.value); 
      },              
   });      
});​
```